# Please help to build SQL SELECT request with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, informix

I have following tables:

```
callrecord table
callid, calltypekey, requeuecount
123     1            -1
123     2            0
123     3            1
234     1            0
234     3            1
435     3            0
435     1            1
567     1            -1
678     1            0

calltypes table
calltypekey, calltypename
1            name1
2            name2
3            name3
```

Following SQL request works fine:

```
SELECT callid, min(requeuecount) as minreq, max(requeuecount) as maxreq
FROM callrecord 
GROUP BY callid
HAVING count(callid) > 1
```

and produce the following result:

```
callid, minreq, maxreq 
123     -1      1
234     0       1
435     0       1
```

I would like to add calltypekey value corresponding to min(requeuecount) record, i.e. result should be the following:

```
callid, minreq, maxreq, minCTK, maxCTK 
123     -1      1       1       3
234     0       1       1       3
435     0       1       3       1
```

or even with joined names:

```
callid, minreq, maxreq, minname, maxname 
123     -1      1       name1    name3
234     0       1       name1    name3
435     0       1       name3    name1
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try.

```
select t1.callid, t1.minreq, t1.maxreq, t2.Name as minname, t3.Name as maxname from (
SELECT callid, min(requeuecount) as minreq, max(requeuecount) as maxreq
FROM callrecord 
GROUP BY callid
HAVING count(callid) > 1) as t1
left join 
    (select c.callid, ct.Name, c.requeuecount from callrecord c
        inner join calltypes ct on ct.calltypekey = c.calltypekey)  t2 on t2.callid = t1.callid and t2.requeuecount = t1.minreq
left join 
    (select c.callid, ct.Name, c.requeuecount from callrecord c
        inner join calltypes ct on ct.calltypekey = c.calltypekey)  t3 on t3.callid = t1.callid and t3.requeuecount = t1.maxreq
```

Comment: after replacing Name to calltypename your code works and produce true result!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select A.callid,minreq,maxreq,C.calltypekey as minCTK,C1.calltypekey as maxCTK  from 
(
  SELECT callid, min(requeuecount) as minreq, max(requeuecount) as maxreq
    FROM callrecord 
    GROUP BY callid
    HAVING count(callid) > 1
)A left join callrecord C on A.minreq=C.requeuecount
   left join callrecord C1 on A.maxreq=C1.requeuecount
```

Comment: No, first one just returns min and max values of requeuecount, not corresponding to min(requeuecount) and max(requeuecount): callid, minreq, maxreq, minCTK, maxCTK 
123     -1      1       1       3
234     0       1       1       3
435     0       1       1       3

Comment: @Vodnik, I've edited the answer - you can check now

Comment: Error 324: Ambiguous column (callid)